# Word for "product version that was scheduled to be released but never was, in favor of a better version"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Let's say, DirectX 4.0 is never released; Microsoft launches DirectX 5.0 instead. So DirectX 4.0 is like a very special version of DirectX that is never made public for whatever reason.

Is there a word for an act like this (preferably a verb), or for an unreleased version of that kind (preferably a past participle)?

More generally, you have made a product, version 1.0. But you decide that it should stay unreleased. You make a better version 1.5 and release that one. Is there an apt word that describes (what happened to) version 1.0?

Comment: I hope the question is more complete and intelligible now. I apologise for posting a vague question previously. I was in a hurry when I first posted this. Sorry.

Comment: Unreleased is the word you are looking for.

Comment: I had people in my previous office use a word that perfectly describes this with a touch of humor. We called it a Betaflop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [*shelve*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/shelve#shelve_4):

> to decide not to use something such as a plan or suggestion now, although you may use it later

or [*scrap*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/scrap_16#scrap_20):

> to decide not to continue with something such as a plan or an event; to get rid of something

Comment: Shelve, definitely.

Comment: Shelve is probably the best word, but in a slightly different context, you might also 'skip' a version number as well to bring it inline with other products on the same (higher) version number. What 'skip' doesn't imply is whether or not that version of the software was changed along with the version.

Answer (score 0):

In the automotive world these are referred to as ***concept cars***

***Prototype*** almost works, but typically a *prototype* is an early version of something that *is* intended to be released to the public, while the ***proof-of-concept*** is really just for internal use and is never intended to be released.

Another option is to refer to these as ***in-house*** products.  Many companies will develop in-house, ***proprietary***, tools that they use themselves but never intend to sell.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a verb.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a good thing, you'd probably say the earlier version was *superseded* before it could be released.  To be more precise, it *stayed in-house*, *remained experimental* or *under development*, *never shipped*, *never released*, *never made it past beta or alpha*, etc.

To paint it negatively, you'd probably say the first version was *vaporware*.